# How should we interpret the variable created by Principal Component Analysis?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-mining, data-transformation

I tried to model $\text{Saving} = a + b_1*\text{Income} + b_2*\text{Wealth}$ but found that $\text{Income}$ and $\text{Wealth}$ were highly correlated. I applied PCA to get a new variable $\text{New}$ based on the first component. Next, I modeled $\text{Saving} = c + b_3*\text{New}$. I then had two questions as follows:

1. How should I interpret the model: $\text{Saving} = c + b_3*\text{New}$?
2. If it would not make any sense to interpret $\text{Saving} = c + b_3*\text{New}$, should I replace $\text{New}$ with the corresponding weights (loadings) generated by PCA? The weights regarding $\text{New}$ were $1.5*\text{Income} + 2*\text{Wealth}$. (I mean should I do $\text{Saving} = c + b_3*(1.5*\text{Income} + 2*\text{Wealth})$ instead?)

Comment: Did you mean to include Income twice when defining New?

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly do you mean by "loadings"; the projections or the eigenvectors themselves? (There's a typo as Dimitriy has also spotted)

Comment: @GuessGucci, Not "loadings". Loadings are the coefficients to predict an original variable by component(s), To predict vice versa, use eigenvector elements as the coefficients. Also, you should initially center all your variables, because PCA is a regressional model without intercept.

Comment: Do you mean I should not use "1.5*Income + 2*Wealth" as a replacement of the variable "New?" I used "prcomp" in R; could you please let me know how to get eigenvector elements? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you define `New`, which in the standard PCA terminology is the direction of the largest variation in your dataset, is just a linear combination of your existing data.

Your question (1) is answered by your question (2) practically. Yes, you can use the projections generated by PCA. Yes you can use the equivalent linear combination of your original values but make sure you are using zero-centred data to begin with. (Usually PCA acts a bit like "eigendecomposion(covariance(data))" to get the eigenvectors that represent the principal modes of variation in your dataset and then it projects your original (zero-centred) dataset on the space defined by the eigenvectors.)

Comment: My PCA was based on the correlation matrix, and the weights were re-scaled already. Is that what you mean "using zero-centred data?"

Comment: No, I mean really zero-centred; eg. the column of that stores `Income` having a mean of 0. Using the correlation matrix instead of the covariance matrix is nothing to do with this. The correlation matrix is just your covariance matrix scaled to variance 1 along the diagonal.

Comment: You are right; it should be "the data (not weights) were re-scaled already."